# python pdf (PyPDF2 module) - How to split/merge this?

Tags: python, pypdf

I was trying to split & merge pdf files so that i can remove the first page of each pdf files.. Here's the code.

```
    #python3

    #split and merge pdf files!


    import os, PyPDF2

    pdfFiles = []
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Cyber\\Downloads\\5-111-fall-2008\\5-111-fall-2008\\contents\\readings-and-lecture-notes')



    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if filename.endswith('pdf'):
            pdfFiles.append(filename)

    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for filename in pdfFiles:
        pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

        for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
            pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

    pdfOutput = open('Merged.pdf', 'wb')
    pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
    pdfOutput.close()
```

And then i get the following error...

: PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]

I searched for that error and found out that it indicates there may have been an issue with the creation of the PDF itself.

Though i get my merged.pdf file as i wanted, i want to know what that exactly  means & how to avoid getting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning means that the first section of the xref table does not begin with object zero. There may have been an error in writing the PDF. If strict = False, PyPDF2 will try to correct the object ID numbers. If strict = True, they will not be corrected.The default is True. Try `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj,False)`

Comment: Thanks! Now i get it. Just to be clear, even though i get the same error message next time, it doesn't actually affect the output of the pdf i want to merge, right? It just let me know the fact that the xref table does not begin with object zero?